# NGINX reverse proxy SSL config

Tags: nginx, ssl, https, configuration, certificate

I tried to setup a NGINX docker container configured as a reverse proxy on my local net to enable SSL encryption towards the Internet.
I used certbot to generate certificates with the DNS method(I use a dynamic DNS to track my dynamic IP) using this script since I can't open port 80 on my modem to make the challenges. Script: (https://raw.githubusercontent.com/joohoi/acme-dns-certbot-joohoi/master/acme-dns-auth.py). It worked as expected as it said to insert a CNAME record on my ddns as I did then hit enter and the certificate is rightly created in my letsencrypt directory.

Now here is the problem, when I start my NGINX container it gives me this message:(https://i.stack.imgur.com/phpew.png).
I am a noob regarding certificates, NGINX and self hosting so I may have missed something or have wrong configuration.

I tried many things like converting the certificate in another format and moving cert files around but with no result

Here is a github project with my docker and NGINX configurations:

https://github.com/Ale9600/nginx-reverse-ssl-proxy-config/tree/master/config

Comment: Resolved, the first certificate in the fullchain need to begin with begin trusted certificate and end with that as well BUT only the first one